# Why translations do not work in ModelChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django and I have that code :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django import forms

auth_d = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            label=_('Water'),
    )
```

I wrote the translations in the django.po file and then I typed that `compilesmessages` and I have not the translation.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: What do you get instead of the translation?

Comment: Actually I get 'Water' instead of 'Agua"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I finished to find the solution, my translations were defined as "fuzzy" so I used :

`compilemessages --use-fuzzy`